# ASP.NET href CSS not being applied

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

CSS isn't being applied in aspx page. It works when the css is defined in the same page (href references a.classname) but when it is put into a stylesheet it is not applied. When element is inspected, Chrome says user agent stylesheet is being applied.

It says that a:-webkit-any-link is being applied to hyperlinks (user agent stylesheet)

Any ideas why this isn't working?

I reference the class for the hyperlink using:

```
<div class="summaryitem"><a ID="hl" runat="server" href="" class="someclassname">Hyperlink CSS should be applied to this</a>
```

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
a.someclassname:link { 
    font-weight: bold;   
    color: #555;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
a.someclassname:visited { 
    font-weight: bold;   
    color: #555;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
a.someclassname:hover { 
    font-weight: bold;   
    color: #555;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
a.someclassname:active { 
    font-weight: bold;   
    color: #555;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
```

Comment: could you show us your code where you reference the stylesheet document? maybe the path is incorrectly specified? relative versus absolute is what i'm thinking at the moment...

Comment: The path is correct as other elements in the page use css from the same stylesheet.

Comment: It says that a:-webkit-any-link is being applied to hyperlinks (user agent stylesheet)

Comment: I've updated my question with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in a partial view, just be sure the parent view includes the CSS ref.

EDIT: wow got a similar problem a few minutes ago. I've solved testing my view with Chrome and using the network auditing feature (at the page hit F12, click on Network and then reload your page). Should tell you at least if your CSS is correctly sent to the browser. (my problem was I wasn't referencing the correct CSS).

EDIT-2:
I usually refer to CSS via:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/fg.menu.css")" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But I'm using MVC with Razor views, I've noticed that putting CSS out of the Content folder can be nasty on ASP.NET.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not properly added your stylesheet, does it resemble something like this

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/mylayout.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
```

Comment: It is added in that way. But it seems to still not be applied

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following

1. Check the href location that you are refering is correct.
2. Try to delete the offline files in your browser
3. Check your class name correctly mapped..